# Where to find source code used for testing Scipy?

Tags: python, testing, scipy

Where can we find the source code used by Scipy to test its library functions? So far, I have got two clues. One is to use

```
import scipy
scipy.test('full')
```

for testing Scipy. Another clue is that Scipy should use CI for continuous testing:

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/ci/azure-travis-template.yaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the project documentation, you can find the [testing guidelines](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/dev/contributor/runtests.html).

Testing is supposed to happen with a copy of the full project from https://github.com/scipy/scipy

The project uses a test runner that relies on [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/) that you must install beforehand. This is the case if you installed the conda environment provided (in `environment.yml` in the github repo, for instance).